# Wait for element to exist using while loop and browser refresh in javascript and webdriver-io

Tags: javascript, while-loop, webdriver-io

Trying to write a function using the while loop where we are forcing a browser refresh until an element exists. Currently the link element is taking over 30secs to appear and only when the page is refreshed.

A colleague did a hack below, using an existing function in our code "findLink". But that too is using a webdriver-io api "waitForExist" which has it's own timeout which fails the test as it timeouts before the end of the loop.

Any suggestions on how we can best fix this?

```
async waitForRelatedCaseRecordToExistB() {
        const sleep = (time = 0) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
        const waitTime = 20000;
        let i = 0;
        logger.info("Waits for Related Case link element to appear...");
        let caseLink;
        while (i < 12) {
            await sleep(waitTime);
            await browser.refresh();
            await sleep(waitTime);
            await browser.refresh();
            caseLink = await (await this.findLink("Related Case")).getAttribute("href");
            // elem = await $(`//*[text()='Related Case']/ancestor::div/following-sibling::div/span//slot/force-lookup//a`);
            // const elem = await $(`//*[text()='Related Case']/ancestor::div/following-sibling::div/span//slot/force-lookup//a/slot//span`);
            logger.info(`Retry: ${i + 1}        Element: ${caseLink}`);
            if (caseLink.isDisplayed()) {
                break;
            }
            i += 1;
        }
        logger.info(`Related Case linked to Case Event is displayed`);
    }
```

Comment: simply use MutationObserver?

Comment: @MisterJojo never heard of it. Just having a read of it now. Have you used it before?